# Debug javascript from a generated page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In my application I made some computing server side with a Javascript interpreter. I'd like to take advantage from F12 debug engine in my browser chroome to let the user debug his scripts. To do that a generare a new page and open it in a new window

```
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "/test/tipoManufatto", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                var new_window = window.open(null, '');
                new_window.document.write(this.responseText);

            }
        };
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify($scope.tc.selected));
```

the page is generated correctly and the server side generated scripts runs fine but if get into F12 tools

[image]

I cannot see my script in the source tab therefore I cannot set any breakpoints.
[image]

Is there a better way to open a dynamically generated page in a new window? I need to generate the page from the back-end with a POST verb in order to send some data.

Here is what my network tabs looks like
[image]

Comment: Look at the "Network" tab and see what the server responds. You'll see your script there. Also, `$scope`, this means you're in AngularJS, any reason why you are using `new XMLHttpRequest()` instead of Angular's HTTP service?

Comment: my network tab of my calling page looks fine. The response type is 200 and the response body is what I expect. I suspect the problem rises from the way I open the new window. I first create an empty one then I inject its content

Comment: And what about using Angular's HTTP service instead of the vanilla (and old) `XMLHttpRequest()`?